# PHP MYSQL family tree 'about' page

Tags: php, mysql, family-tree

I build a family tree.
The table looks like this:

> id------firstname------mother------father-------kids

this is the code for person detals page:

> $query = mysql_query(" SELECT family.id,   family.firstname, 
>   mother.firstname AS `mother`, father.firstname AS `father`, kids.firstname AS `kids`
>
> FROM family
>
> JOIN family AS mother  ON mother.id = family.mother JOIN family AS
>   father  ON father.id = family.father JOIN family AS
>   kids ON kids.id = family.kids
>
> WHERE family.id=".$_GET['id']
>
> $row = mysql_fetch_array($query,) or die(mysql_error());
>
> ```
>           echo "First Name: ".$row['firstname']."<BR>";
>           echo "Mother Name: ".$row['mother']."<BR>"; 
>           echo "Father Name:  ".$row['father']."<BR>"; 
>           echo "Kids: ".$row['kids']."<BR>";
>           echo "<BR>";
> ```

the result is: 
First Name : XXXXX 
Mother Name : YYYYY 
Kids : AAAAAAA

The problem is when one of the fields are empty (if some person have no kids), script stops. and I get only:

First Name : 
Mother Name : 
Kids :

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fields aren't required to have a value you should use `LEFT JOIN`instead of `JOIN` although this can result in quite heavy loading, depending on your amount of data.

Comment: Thank you, any solution to make the loading faster?

Comment: Well, you could split it up in several SQL queries and test beforehand if there's something to select. Then of course indexes. And here's a link for optimizing left and right joins: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html